azure bot issues with WhatsApp integration
I have created the communications channel in communication services, then registered with WhatsApp. Inside whatsapp web management page i can see that azure is one of the apps with permissions. Also see this link which basically describes most of the process.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/advanced-messaging/whatsapp/connect-whatsapp-business-account
However when i send a message to the WhatsApp business number i get no response from the bot. The bot is working fine as a webchat on a webpage. I don't see anything wrong, except for a status on the communication resource awaiting "Display name review not started" by whatsap Meta. But it did say that my WhatsApp number is ready to use when i was done with the steps. When i check inside whatsapp for business i see no messages received. The messages sent on my mobile to the business whatsapp never go to blue with 2 ticks. Does this mean that the issue is just with whatsapp not receiving the messages or in Azure?
Not familiar with whatsapp for business but in their console i see 0 messages sent or received. The number was tested before by another team member but we had to re-link for Azure, so maybe messages lost but it says zero messages anyway. We sent many tests to WhatsApp.
Thank you!

Please share your error message.
